# Batch file variables

Tags: variables, batch-file

So I have this batch file to backup some programs and also restore them if needed.  I have it automated to create folders with the current date each time these programs are backed up.  So far I have it set so you can enter a variable as one of the current folder dates that are backed up and when entered correctly it will display "**CMS restore completed ! ! !**" however, if nothing is entered or the wrong date is entered it will still display "**CMS restore completed ! ! !**"

I would to be able to use the dates in a txt file to validate this variable so only the dates shown in the txt file will allow the rest of the batch file to run.  I would like it to be able to tell me that an invalid date not shown in the txt file will not allow the batch file to keep running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

BATCH FILE BELOW

```
$:CMS
@ECHO OFF
cd\1\mybackup\
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO        CURRENT BACKUP DATES ON DISK
ECHO.
type list.txt
ECHO.
ECHO Input date to restore CMS and press Enter.
ECHO i.e. YYYY-MM-DD
SET /p VARIABLE=
xcopy /e /y c:\1\mybackup\%VARIABLE%\CMS c:\CMS
CLS
ECHO CMS Restored ! ! !
PAUSE
GOTO 2
```

VARIABLES FROM TEXT FILE BELOW

```
2013-08-05
2013-08-06
2013-08-07
New Folder
New Folder (2)
New Folder (3)
New Folder (4)
New Folder (5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
cd\1\mybackup\
CLS
:again
ECHO.
ECHO        CURRENT BACKUP DATES ON DISK
ECHO.
type list.txt | find "-"
ECHO.
ECHO Input date to restore CMS and press Enter.
ECHO i.e. YYYY-MM-DD
SET "VARIABLE="
SET /p VARIABLE=
if not defined variable echo Nothing entered?&goto again
type list.txt|findstr /i /b /e "%variable%" >nul
if errorlevel 1 echo Invalid date entered&goto again
xcopy /e /y c:\1\mybackup\%VARIABLE%\CMS c:\CMS
CLS
ECHO CMS Restored to %variable% ! ! !
...
```

Notes:

- added label `:again` to repeat question
- piped LIST.TXT through FIND to show only lines containing "-" (ie. dates)
- Set variable to NOTHING as `SET/P` with just <kbd>enter</kbd> will leave the variable
  UNCHANGED, not clear it.
- Detect nothing-entered; respond and prompt again
- match any line from `list.txt` to string entered - full match `/b` begins `/e` and ends `/i` but case-insensitive.

  - Could pipe through `FIND` again to match against date-type line if required.
- If entered data not found in file, report and prompt again
- Added restore-entry to `CMS Restored` message.

Comment: Peter, that is brilliant and works just as I was hoping for.  Thank you so very much!!!!!  I am testing everything up to this point and if any issues will post again.  If you don't hear anything, all went well.  Thank you again!!!!

Comment: +1 - This is basically the solution I was goint to write. However, your FINDSTR should probably be using the `/C:"%variable%"` option, just in case the entered value contains spaces. It should also use the `/L` option to force a literal comparison, just in case the entered values has regex meta characters. I would use `|| echo Invalid...` instead of `if errorlevel 1 echo Invalid...`, but that is more a matter of style.

Comment: Peter,  if you are there I have one last question with my batch file.  Not sure how to PM you on here.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to catch no date entered.  I edited to add code to catch invalid date (untested).  Of course it will fail in the year 2100 and you need to decide if you need to be more discretionary.  Corrected!

```
@ECHO OFF
cd\1\mybackup\
:Retry
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO        CURRENT BACKUP DATES ON DISK
ECHO.
type list.txt
ECHO.
ECHO Input date to restore CMS and press Enter.
ECHO i.e. YYYY-MM-DD
SET /p VARIABLE=
IF "%VARIABLE%"=="" ECHO.Please enter a date & PAUSE & GOTO :Retry
FOR /D %%A if (20??-*) DO IF EXIST "%%A" GOTO :DoCopy
ECHO.Please enter a valid date & PAUSE & GOTO :Retry

:DoCopy
xcopy /e /y c:\1\mybackup\%VARIABLE%\CMS c:\CMS
CLS
ECHO CMS Restored ! ! !
PAUSE
GOTO 2
```

Comment: That caught the "no date entered" problem!!!  Do you know of a way to catch it if you enter the date incorrectly?  I was wanting to somehow compare the date entered against the dates in the text file that is created.

Comment: Use IF EXIST (see IF /?)

Comment: It is not that great... which is why I added the remark that the OP shoukd use more discretion if needed.  FOR /D %%A if (20??-*) DO IF EXIST "%%A"

Comment: I provided an example of the text file above with dates in them and new folders.  I use "dir /ad /B /o:n > list.txt" to grab a list of current folders in a directory and print them to a text file.  I would like to use those entries in the text file as a safeguard when entering a date as a variable for this batch file.  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks, you guys are being extremely helpful.